# Wrong links in API Documentation

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, documentation

`/docs/me-posts` and `/docs/me-network-activity` are inaccessible from the main /docs/ page.  Instead, their links point to what the domain interprets as a malformed request (i.e. `/docs/me/posts`) and it errors out.

#### Reproduce

Search for `me/posts` on the main [documentation index page](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs).  Click and see.

#### Fix

Change both

- `/docs/me/posts` and
- `/docs/me/network-activity`

to

- `/docs/me-posts` and
- `/docs/me-network-activity`

respectively. Note the hyphen.

Comment: I should note that these were found with a [scraper](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236945/188148)---there's no way I would have found these otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links in docs for these are now fixed.

Thanks for reporting!