# Can we use straight XML/XSLT for the meat of the API documentation?

Tags: feature-request, api, documentation, xml

This would make it much easier to create the bulk of language-specific wrappers (using a different XSLT or your favourite XML parsing tool).  As it stands now, the documentation contains little semantic meaning within the source and makes it needlessly difficult to scrape through.  A little bit of XSLT/CSS could solve this handily.

I have been working on a [scraper in Python](https://github.com/vermiculus/stack-api) that is attempting to work with the current system.  It can and should be used to perform the great bulk of the work if this gets a green-light.

(Believe it or not, this is a version 3 overhaul of the scraper, probably the final such overhaul if the documentation isn't re-factored.  Much of the implementation remains and will be completed tonight, but I believe the general approach now is solid.)

#### History

I will note that [earlier versions of the API were reflective](https://stackapps.com/q/4792/11299); you could make an API request that returned all API information.  This proved to be too much effort to maintain.  I don't propose this be brought back; I agree that it would too much to maintain within the API itself, but perhaps it would not be out of the question to just maintain a downloadable XML database of the API and have XSLT/XHTML present it for the browser.

#### Related

- [How is the Stack Exchange API documentation generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191545/188148)
- [Can I retrieve the API interfaces via the API?](https://stackapps.com/q/4792/11299)

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd be more than happy to provide a baseline for this new format. I'm going to be creating the XML database, anyway.